# Showing double orthogonal complement of subspace is equal to the subspace in degenerate case

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is similar to some previous questions, however this particular question has not been answered before on this site (I have spent the past hour searching for it).

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\beta : V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ is a symmetric bilinear form on $V$, also suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

I want to show $(W^\perp)^\perp = W$, the inclusion of $W$ in $(W^\perp)^\perp$ is obvious but I'm struggling to show the other direction since we don't know that $\beta$ is non-degenerate (which is the case every answer on this site is for).

I'm sure I am just missing something obvious, thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: It is not true. Take the zero symmetric form, and for $W$ the zero dimensional subspace. Every $.^\perp$ is the whole space $V$.

Comment: It seems you are correct, this is an exercise I'm trying in preparation for a Lie algebras exam and was set by my lecturer; I will email her and ask. Do you know if we require that $\beta$ is non-degenerate to complete this proof?

Comment: The usual argument for a non-degenerate form is using dimension (provided $V$ is finite dimensional): the dimension of $W^\perp$ is the codimension (in $V$) of $W$, so $\dim((W^\perp)^\perp)=\dim W$, which together with $W\subseteq(W^\perp)^\perp$ suffices. I don't think the result is true even in the non-degenerate case when $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.